# Is there any meaningful difference in acidity level between beer styles?

Tags: style, ingredients

I would guess that a Porter pH is higher than for an IPA, because of alpha acids or other acids from the hops. I also heard that it can heavily  depend on the acidity of the water used.

But anyway, are those pH differences really significant in the final product ? For instance, if I have an ulcer, would it be worse to drink some type of beer rather than an other ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, there are major differences in acidity. Unsurprisingly, the sour beer styles can have very low pH levels. [Here's](http://www.themadfermentationist.com/2011/11/measuring-sour-beer-ph.html) an example of someone measuring the pH of sour beers and finding that even within that category there are significant differences. [Here's](http://www.weyermann.de/downloads/pdf/Weyermann_TKW_Mash-pH_2010.pdf) a short presentation showing that expected pH ranges from 3.2-3.4 for Berliner Weisse to 4.5-4.8 for pilsner and bock. So, yes, there are definitely major differences, and they do matter to the perception of the finished product. At the most obvious level, low-pH beers actually taste sour. There are also indications that smaller pH variations matter to how people perceive the flavour.

Answer (score 2):

Well, brewers typically control pH during the fermentation process top avoid unwanted bacterial growth, etc., fermentation actually doesn't even happen below ~4. So not a significant difference.

Sources - I brew and [web](http://gillesenergies.webs.com/phinfermentation.htm)